# Create a new field in an MS SQL database table using php

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I need to add a new field to a table in an MS SQL database using a php script.
I've tried using the below statment:

$query = ("ALTER TABLE 'TableName' ADD $FieldName char(10)")

I've tried connecting to the database with mssql_connect() and PDO(). Both fail without any errors in php or apache.
I've tried hardcoding the values in in the statement instead of using variables but that also fails.
If I run the statement directly on the database server it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This work fine.
try this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE `testNew` ADD `ID2` INT NOT NULL");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That actually throws a syntax error when executed in php and on the SQL server.

Comment: I ran it without the '' around the table name and field name. It work on the SQL server but failed in php.
Also, I need to actually pass the new field name as a php variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$tbl = "YOUR TABLE NAME";
$col = "YOUR COLUMN NAME";    
$stmt = $conn->prepare("ALTER TABLE `$tbl` ADD `$col` INT NOT NULL");
$stmt->execute()
```

Comment: That produce the exact same result as the first suggestion.